# How to get to the file on the hosting located in the private folder?

Tags: php

How to get to the file on the hosting located in the private folder?
The private and public_html folders are in one main directory. I will add that I test in the same way under xampp and everything works correctly, and now there are errors on the hosting. I did not set any passwords to the folder, I simply copied the folder (FileZilla) on the hosting

> Warning: require_once(../../private/initialize.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/index.php on line 1
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../../private/initialize.php' (include_path='.:/:/usr/local/php71/lib/pear') in /home/index.php on line 1

Under the xampp I will get to the file with this line:

```
<?php require_once('../../private/initialize.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Possibly a permissions issue, but your question is somewhat unclear.

Comment: Jup, permissions or an incorrect path. Perhaps the wrong number of `../`'s..

Comment: What is "private folder"? What is the "public_html" folder? How do you set passwords on folders? I don't understand what you are trying to tell us (but I suspect its probably a result of the wrong permissions)

Comment: if you're running from `/home/index.php`, then `../` will point to the root directory, and `../../` doesn't exist. You have to set the proper path, which on a remote server isn't necessarily the same as on your own pc

Comment: You're using a relative path in your `require_once()`. Try `echo getcwd();` to see where your code is executing at the time you try  `require_once('../../private/initialize.php');`.